# Flatten nested json from API in python with id outside string

Tags: python, json, flatten, unnest

How can I flatten this json and create a table with the id presented in the table ?

Json file structure as below is present as a string in a large table

| id | date | json |
| --- | --- | --- |
| cell 1 | 2022-04-01 | json string as below |
| cell 2 | 2022-04-01 | json string as below |

```
 [
      {
        "a": {
          "b": [
            {
              "c": "1",
              "d": "2",
              "e": "3",
              "f": "4"
            }
          ]
        },
        "g": {
          "h": "5",
          "i": "6"
        }
      }
    ]
```

I have tried below yet it doens't seem to split it correctly.

```
 pd.DataFrame(pd.json_normalize(df,record_path=["a","b"],["g"]))
```

I am expecting a data frame that i can work with